# HTML / CSS Image disapear after animation

Tags: html, css, image, animation

I made a animated logo for my Website but it is not working :/

The animation is not working in Waterfox and IE and in Chrome it is buggy. After I hover over the image and the animation stops the image disapears.

Example: https://blender4me.de/logo/

My html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Blender4Me
        </title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="logo.css"/>

    </head>

    <body id="header">
        <!-- Mittleres Feld -->
        <div class="mid">
            <a href="#" > <img class="logo" src="inner_outer_circle.gif"/> </a>
            <a href="#" class="rotate"> <img class="logo" src="mid_circle.gif"/> </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css code:

```
#header
{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background: #222222 none;
}

.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}  

.rotate:hover  
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

.logo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 1024px;
}

div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 1024px;
    border: 20px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Maybe you have an idea what's going on, and know how to fix the problem with the different browsers :3

Comment: Seems not the case in [this demo](http://jsbin.com/daxovu/3/edit?html,css,output) (tested in Chrome)

Comment: try adding `transform:rotate(0deg);` for `.rotate`

Comment: You are right, but in Waterfox it doesnt work, and in IE it looks buggy

Comment: fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/to9q3z4a/1/

Comment: So, what could be the reason why its not working on my website/localhost?